# Can I count unique values of a column and add counts as seperate columns for each unique value, preferably seperately for each subject?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, data-preprocessing

For example, I have my data in the following form:

```
    Group Product
0      1       A
1      1       A
2      1       B
3      2       A
4      2       B
5      2       C
6      3       A
7      3       C
8      3       C
```

What I would like to achieve is having it be like the following:

```
   Group  A  B  C
0      1  2  1  0
1      2  1  1  1
2      3  1  0  1
```

Where values of A, B and C columns are respectively their occurences for the given group.

How can I achieve this using pandas?

I tried using groupby and count with the following code

```
df.groupby(['Group','Product'])['Product'].count()
```

Which provided me with the results I wanted however I have no idea how to put them into seperate columns for each count.

Comment: See question #5

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas.crosstab):

```py
x = pd.crosstab(df['Group'], df['Product']).reset_index()
x.columns.name = None

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   Group  A  B  C
0      1  2  1  0
1      2  1  1  1
2      3  1  0  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas pivot_table should do it.

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Group', columns='Product', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()
pivot_df.columns.name = None

print(pivot_df)
```